# react select drop down on change Issue in the edit mode

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am currently using react-select library to my project

[react-select](http://%20%20%20%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select)

This is my create invoice page, Please check below view,
When user select the PO drop down, red colored text boxes are automatically filled. It is working well.

[image]

This is my invoice list page view[image]

When user click the action button, data passed and redirect to the create invoice page. Currently object passed and PO number set correctly. but other fields did not filled automatically.

PO NO is set correctly. But on change function did not fired and did not set other text box values.

[image]

This is my drop down and onchanges function.

```
   <Select
            options={options}
            value={values.purchaseOrderNumber}
            onChange={onChange} onFocus={onChange}
            name="purchaseOrderNumber"
          />
  const onChange = (selectedOP) => {

setInputValue(selectedOP);
loadselectedValue(selectedOP);
//handleChange(selectedOP);
console.log(selectedOP);
```

};

I know this codes not enough to give better solution. but if you can please tell me the correct path to do this using react hooks. thanks